# Rails: separate app to 2 domains, separate user to each domain by user_type, cannot login cross domain depends on user_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cross-domain

I have rails application with Devise for manage authentication, I have 2 domains that access to this application like domain1.com, domain2.com. each domain is for each type of user like user_type1 can login on domain1.com and user_type2 can login on domain2.com, but if user_type1 login on domain2.com, server must redirect to domain1.com automatically, from this requirement I don't know how to implements. could you suggest how to please?, I'm quite new for ruby on rails, thanks in advance (sorry for my english in some sentense)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the devise `after_sign_in_path_for` method might do the trick for you.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # add your redirection logic based on the user-type here.
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, it works great on redirect to another domain at the login page

but on the previous domain, it recognizes the user is logged in, Is there a way like you log in on domain1 and make it redirect to domain2 with carrying login session too and destroy login session on domain1? thank you